# Get current list/library from http handler

Tags: 2007, publishing-site, rss

I’m trying to write a Http Handler to generate rss xml (based on the CKS code).

I want to be able to get the list/library that the end point of the url is referring to.

For example if my Url is:

- http://example.org/pressreleases/pages/rss.xml

I want to be able to get the pages library of the 'press releases' web.

On a side note if I'm going about this in the wrong way please let me know.

**Update 1**

It may be easier for me to show my code (incase of retardation)

```
public void ProcessRequest(HttpContext context)
    {

        try
        {
            SPList list = SPContext.Current.Web.GetListFromUrl(context.Request.Path);
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            context.Response.Write("Error getting list from spcontext.current.web.GetListFromUrl: " + ex.Message + "<br />");
        }

        try
        {
            SPList list = SPContext.Current.List;
            context.Response.Write("List title: " + list.Title.ToString() + "<br />");
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            context.Response.Write("Error getting list from spcontext.current.list: " + ex.Message + "<br />");
        }

        try
        {
            context.Response.Write("List Title from SPConext: " + SPContext.Current.List.Title.ToString());
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            context.Response.Write("Error getting list from spcontext.current.list.title.tostring: " + ex.Message + "<br />");                
        }

    }
```

The error messages displayed are...

- Error getting list from spcontext.current.web.GetListFromUrl: Cannot complete this action. Please try again.
- Error getting list from spcontext.current.list: Object reference not set to an instance of an object.
- Error getting list from spcontext.current.list.title.tostring: Object reference not set to an instance of an object.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've managed to get the list name by string manipulation.

Answer (score 2):

You have access to SPContext within a HTTP handler, so you should be able to use:

```
SPContext.Current.List
```

If for some reason that *can't* be used, this should get you there:

```
SPContext.Current.Web.GetListFromUrl()
```

Comment: That's what I thought, however when I try with the first statement I get an: 
“Object reference not set to an instance of an object.”
error and the second statement gives the error: 
“Cannot complete this action. Please try again.”

Which is very weird as SPContext.Current.Site and SPContext.Current.Web both work.

Comment: Hmm strange - I'm pretty sure I've written code like this in a HTTP handler before.

Is it perhaps that SPContext *is* populated by the .List property isn't?

Comment: Hi Chris thanks for replying, i've posted my code as it might be easier to see if i'm making a mistake somewhere else.